# Navigation bar does not work (with JS, css, HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[*ADDITIONAL BELOW*]

I have done my first portfolio on my won and my code of navigation bar with JS, css, HTML doesn't work even I tried everything out for many times.

The navigation bar shows up but the event doesn't happen.(and the menu shows up every time I load the page.) Maybe because the code of JavaScript wrong? Could anyone help me out please?

```
// JavaScript //

document
  .querySelector('.btn-mobile-nav')
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('.btn-mobile-nav');
    document.querySelector('.mobile-menu').classList.toggle('.is-active');
  });
```

```
// HTML //

 <nav class="nav">
        <div class="main-nav">
          <ul class="main-nav-list mobile-menu">
            <li>
              <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#intro"
                >introduce</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#aboutme"
                >about me</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#work">work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#skill">skill</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <button class="btn-mobile-nav">
        <ion-icon class="icon-mobile-open" name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
        
      </button>
```

```
// CSS //

  .btn-mobile-nav {
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.658);
    border: none;
    height: 3.2rem;
    width: 3.2rem;

    top: 0.2rem;
    right: 0.2rem;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .icon-mobile-open {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
  }

  .mobile-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #555;
  }

  .mobile-menu-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;

    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  /* before */
  .mobile-menu {
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  /* after  */
  .mobile-menu .is-active {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

[*ADDITIONAL QUESTION*]

And one more question... I want to close this navigation when the list item is clicked but only the first list item works and other does not...

```
document.querySelector('a[href^="#"]').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.mobile-menu').classList.remove('is-active');
});
```

Comment: There may be other issues, but one thing is: You need the class name `is-active`, not its selector `.is-active` in the `toggle()`

Comment: You also have a space between `.mobile-menu .is-active` in your CSS, which looks for an `.is-active` on a child element of `.mobile-menu` rather than the same element with both classes. (Remove the space to look for a single element with both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- You need to pass in a class name (not a selector) to `.toggle()` (Remove the `.` from the `toggle('.is-active')`)
- You need to select the same element with both the `mobile-menu` and `is-active` classes in your CSS (Done by removing the space between `.mobile-menu .is-active`)

```js
document
  .querySelector('.btn-mobile-nav')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('.btn-mobile-nav');
    document.querySelector('.mobile-menu').classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
```

```css
.btn-mobile-nav {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.658);
  border: none;
  height: 3.2rem;
  width: 3.2rem;
  top: 0.2rem;
  right: 0.2rem;
  z-index: 2;
  
  /*Added to make the example clearer*/
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.icon-mobile-open {
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.mobile-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #555;
}

.mobile-menu-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* before */

.mobile-menu {
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}


/* after  */

.mobile-menu.is-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-list mobile-menu">
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#intro">introduce</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#aboutme">about me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#work">work</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link mobile-menu-item" href="#skill">skill</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<button class="btn-mobile-nav">
  <ion-icon class="icon-mobile-open" name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
</button>
```